# using 'extern' for integer array results in segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, extern

I have the following code:

File1.c

```
int arr[10];
```

File2.c

```
extern int *arr;
int main()
{
    arr[0] = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Please explain me why accessing the arr in File2.c will cause segmentation fault?
compiler:gcc
OS:Linux.

Comment: Maybe there is a reason the first one is called "array", while the second is called "pointer"?

Comment: You've not told the compiler the truth,,you've told it there's a variable named `arr` that's an int pointer, but it's actually an array of ints, which is quite different from a pointer to an int.

Comment: @Olaf: yes 'pointer' arr pointing to first element in the array.

Comment: @Pradeep_Evol: No, it does not! You invoke UB. An array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array. Please read the standard. And use a header you include in both files! The compiler is your friend. Let it help you detect type errors.

Comment: @Olaf: What header will help the compiler detect this type error?                  But in case of character array, array is a pointer . am I correct?

Comment: @Pradeep_Evol: Just as you apparently missed the point: No, it is not a pointer! Because it is an **array**. It is called "array" because it is **not** a pointer! If it **was** a pointer, it would be called "pointer"! Hope that was now clear enough (otherwise I cannot help you further). Please read a C book. You will also see what a header actually is for and how it will help you.

Comment: `extern int *arr;` is a **pointer** that **points to an integer**.  `int arr[10];` is an array **of** integers.  A pointer contains an address - which may or may not be valid.  An array contains values of whatever base type makes up the array.

Comment: @Pradeep_Evol *But in case of character array, array is a pointer . am I correct?*  No.  A bare array in a statement is **treated as an address that can be assigned to a pointer**.  Thus `int array[10]; int *pointer = array;` is valid, but that's only because the bare `array` in the second statement is **treated** as the address of the first element of the array.  It's not a pointer - it's the same as `&(array[0])`.

Answer (score 2):

**Reason of error:**

This code lead to segmentation fault

```
int * some_pointer;
...
some_pointer[0] = 1;
```

**You are misunderstood:**

The `extern int *arr;` is declaration of a pointer.

The `int arr[10];` is a declaration of an array.

They do not have any relative in your case.

You just need `extern int arr[10];` in File2.c